# Answering Apple Privacy Questions while publishing app

Tags: admob, ios14, apptrackingtransparency

What Apple says [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-privacy-details/) It will be required to submit new apps and app updates to the App Store starting December 8, 2020. On each app’s product page, users can learn about some of the data types the app may collect, and whether that data is linked to them or used to track them. However, I am little bit confused. Some of the third party frameworks like [this one](https://developers.ironsrc.com/ironsource-mobile/ios/apples-privacy-questionnaire-answers-ironsource/) are publishing which data they are using. I am using Firebase/Analytics and Google-Mobile-Ad-SDK. I found a [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/app-store-data-collection) on Firebase but I do not completely understand which data collection is required for that two framework.

Comment: Google Admob iOS - Prepare for Apple's App Store data disclosure requirements - https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/data-disclosure